# adding dynamic conditions to mongoose find nodejs.. AND, OR in a same query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add dynamic conditions using mongoose library

```
var and_cond = { $and: [] };
var or_cond = { $or: [] };
and_cond.$and.push ({ "doc_no" :  /first/i  })
or_cond.$or.push ({ "doc_type" : /third/i  })

TRModel.find(
            and_cond,
            or_cond
       )
```

What I expect something which can give me both **AND** and **OR** condition work in a query,

The above ended in an abrupt query which is wrong obviously.

> title_records.find({ '$and': [ { doc_no: /first/i } ] }, { fields: {
>   '$or': [ { doc_type: /third/i } ] } })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're trying to use two top-level logical operators. To my knowledge, you need to have a single top-level operator from the set of `$and`, `$or`, and `$nor`. You can nest as many as you want within, however.
2. You're passing in two separate object when what you really want to do is merge the two.

It looks like you're trying to perform your query such that you find all documents that match both the `$and` condition AND the `$or` condition. In that case, try the following:

```
TRModel.find({
    $and: [
        and_cond,
        or_cond
    ]
});
```

If, however, you want to use one OR the other, you can simply change the top-level `$and` to `$or`:

```
TRModel.find({
    $or: [
        and_cond,
        or_cond
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first make sure you are [matching the mongoose find parameters](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) which are defined specifically as:

```
MyModel.find({ <conditions> }, { <projections> }, { <options> }, <callback function>);
```

e.g.

```
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }, function (err, docs) {});
```

So you have to make sure your end result is one object going in into the conditions part of the find.

Next thing is you have to make sure you have one operator [from these types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/):

`$and`, `$or`, `$not` and `$not`

As your top level one and then you can nest others inside. 
Like you could have top level `$and` with multiple `$or` inside.